# using symmetry in the siffness method

Tags: matrix-elements

Good day All
while trying to solve this exercice[image]

I tried to find a symmetry plan to make my computations easy

and according to my basic understanding
the symmetry must be in term of:
lenght

- length
- load
- support

so my question is 
can I consider the red line of this picture as an axe of symmetry?
many thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't , because the bound at $1$ is not symmetric to that line.

However note that the hinges No. 2,3,4 are fixed (at least that is the meaning of the symbols employed).
If so, rods 2 and 3 do not come into play and you can cancel them.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, but I still have a lot of confusion in my mind, according to you, it s not a matter of symmetry but a matter of cancelling the fixed rods?!

Comment: yes, exactly that.

Comment: @AmaOuchen and, since the hinge 1 is allowed to slide parallel to rod 1 and orthogonal to rod 4, then (for small movements) you can cancel also rod 4. Then the solution is simple, isn't it?